# TeamCity - FTP Upload to Azure fails

Tags: azure, ftp, teamcity

I am trying to deploy a .Net Core 2.0 project to an Azure web app using a TeamCity build.

There are 3 steps :
1 - Nuget Restore
2 - dotnet publish
3 - FTP Upload

After step 2, I get a folder "Output" with all the stuff I need to copy to my Azure web app.
I configured step 3 to copy the content from this folder to my `wwwroot` folder on the Azure FTP. This step copies 3 DLLs and then displays the following message :

> [Step 3/3] Deployment problem: Failed to upload artifacts via FTP. Reply was: 550 The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process.

Here is the configuration :

[image]

Here are the logs on the agent :

```
[Step 3/3] Uploaded [C:\BuildAgent\work\Output\MyLib\AutoMapper.Net4.dll] (28 KB)
[Step 3/3] > TYPE I
[Step 3/3] < 200 Type set to I.
[Step 3/3] > PASV
[Step 3/3] < 227 Entering Passive Mode (137,135,184,233,39,161).
[Step 3/3] > STOR AutoMapper.dll
[Step 3/3] < 125 Data connection already open; Transfer starting.
[Step 3/3] < 226 Transfer complete.
[Step 3/3] > CWD /site/wwwroot
[Step 3/3] < 250 CWD command successful.
[Step 3/3] Uploaded [C:\BuildAgent\work\Output\MyLib\AutoMapper.dll] (163 KB)
[Step 3/3] > TYPE I
[Step 3/3] < 200 Type set to I.
[Step 3/3] > PASV
[Step 3/3] < 227 Entering Passive Mode (137,135,184,233,39,168).
[Step 3/3] > STOR MyLib.PrecompiledViews.dll
[Step 3/3] < 550 The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process. 
[Step 3/3] Deployment problem: Failed to upload artifacts via FTP. Reply was: 550 The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process. 
[Step 3/3] Step Copy to Azure (FTP Upload) failed
```

I tried to upload the files using FileZilla and everything was ok so I guess the issue is on the TeamCity side.

Comment: maybe you trying to send any log file currently being written?

Comment: maybe Azure file system locking the some file(that's why tools like Unlocker exist). You are not doing anything wrong.

Comment: could you provide a full error with stacktrace from the logs on teamcity agent..

Comment: @daggett I added the logs

Comment: @PMerlet did you ever figure this out?

Comment: @40Alpha No I didn't look into this for a while. Do you have the same issue ?

Comment: @PMerlet, exact same, I also received the error when doing an FTP upload direct from Visual Studio. It seems that the app cannot be running when using this method which is of little use when using some CI strategy like TeamCity.

Answer (score 2):

You have to stop Azure app first:

```
az login --username %AZURE_OWNER_ACCOUNT% --password %AZURE_OWNER_PASSWORD% --tenant %AZURE_TENANT_ID%
az webapp stop --name %AZURE_APP% --resource-group %AZURE_RESOURCE_GROUP% --subscription %AZURE_SUBSCRIPTION_ID%
```

Then do FTP upload (your "Copy to Azure" step above), then start the app back:

```
az login --username %AZURE_OWNER_ACCOUNT% --password %AZURE_OWNER_PASSWORD% --tenant %AZURE_TENANT_ID%
az webapp start --name %AZURE_APP% --resource-group %AZURE_RESOURCE_GROUP% --subscription %AZURE_SUBSCRIPTION_ID%
```

Just fulfill the parameters in the TeamCity project and you're ready to go

P.S. Sometimes you have to wait a bit after the "stop" attempt, as the thing is async

P.P.S. It may be required to join both "az" commands into one-liner script due a bug in Azure CLI tools (as they can fail silently after successfully executing very first az command if run under non-interactive account like SYSTEM), so you could do "az login && az stop" and "az login && az start" accordingly.

P.P.P.S. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/install-azure-cli