# Azure DevOps release FTP upload task fails pretty much every time (but not always)

Tags: ftp, azure-devops

I have a release configured in Azure DevOps, and am having problems with the FTP Upload step, which fails most times, but works once in a while. I am trying to deploy to a regular IIS box, not an Azure subscription, and I only have FTP access to it.

When the release gets to the FTP Upload step, the log shows the following (IP address obscured)...

```
##[section]Starting: FTP Upload
==============================================================================
Task         : FTP upload
Description  : Upload files using FTP
Version      : 2.154.0
Author       : Microsoft Corporation
Help         : https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/ftp-upload
==============================================================================
f71d50fb-1433-4a21-9748-e519c6a8ffcd exists true
connecting to: 1.1.1.1:21
connected: 220 FileZilla Server version 0.9.48 beta written by Tim Kosse (tim.kosse@filezilla-project.org) Please visit http
files uploaded: 0, directories processed: 1, total: 1, remaining: 133, remote directory successfully created/verified: /
File: /AutoMapper.Extensions.Microsoft.DependencyInjection.dll Type: upload Transferred: 0
File: /AutoMapper.Extensions.Microsoft.DependencyInjection.dll Type: upload Transferred: 0
##[error]Unhandled: This socket has been ended by the other party
##[warning]FTPError: 550 can't access file.
connecting to: 1.1.1.1:21
connected: 220 FileZilla Server version 0.9.48 beta written by Tim Kosse (tim.kosse@filezilla-project.org) Please visit http
File: /AutoMapper.Extensions.Microsoft.DependencyInjection.dll Type: upload Transferred: 0
File: /AutoMapper.Extensions.Microsoft.DependencyInjection.dll Type: upload Transferred: 0
##[error]Unhandled: This socket has been ended by the other party
##[warning]FTPError: 550 can't access file.
connecting to: 1.1.1.1:21
connected: 220 FileZilla Server version 0.9.48 beta written by Tim Kosse (tim.kosse@filezilla-project.org) Please visit http
File: /AutoMapper.Extensions.Microsoft.DependencyInjection.dll Type: upload Transferred: 0
File: /AutoMapper.Extensions.Microsoft.DependencyInjection.dll Type: upload Transferred: 0
##[error]Unhandled: This socket has been ended by the other party
##[warning]FTPError: 550 can't access file.
connecting to: 1.1.1.1:21
connected: 220 FileZilla Server version 0.9.48 beta written by Tim Kosse (tim.kosse@filezilla-project.org) Please visit http
##[error]FTPError: 550 can't access file.

host: 1.1.1.1
path: /
files uploaded: 0
directories processed: 1
unprocessed files & directories: 133
##[error]Ftp Upload failed
disconnecting from: 1.1.1.1
##[section]Finishing: FTP Upload
```

Using the same FTP credentials, I can access and upload without any problems using FileZilla.

I saw [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56652279/706346), which suggests that you need to stop the Azure app first, but the suggestion he gives for this doesn't seem to apply to releasing from DevOps, as I can't see where you'd add the lines of code.

Anyone able to help?

Comment: Did you check when uploading the AutoMapper.Extensions.Microsoft.DependencyInjection.dll file, it is used by the app? You may try to set the ftp upload task before deploy task.

Comment: @LuMike Yes the file is used. Don't understand your last sentence though, what do you mean by "You may try to set the ftp upload task before deploy task"?

Comment: I mean that if the ftp upload task runs after deploy task, the dll  may be locked by the app instance, so that ftp client could not access the file.

Comment: @LuMike Thanks for the clarification, but I don't think that should be the issue. The release produces a zip file (why I don't know), and I have a task to unzip that, then another one to upload the files. I don't see how the files being uploaded could be locked, as they aren't being used. I think it's the file on the server that's the problem.

Comment: ‘FTPError: 550 can't access file’ generally means the file is open,locked,missed, or the current user has no permission to access. Please check the upload file path is correct and the permission.

Comment: @LuMike As I said in my question, I can upload the files manually without any problems using the same credentials, so I don't think that's it. Thanks anyway.

Comment: I am having the same problem I get `##[warning]Could not find any files to upload` and i don't know how to resolve it. I posted this for help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58966579/how-do-i-configure-a-build-on-vsts-to-ftp-deploy

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use command lines, add [Azure CLI task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/deploy/azure-cli?view=azure-devops)

Otherwise, you can also stop an App Service with [Azure App Service Manage task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/deploy/azure-app-service-manage?view=azure-devops)

But, if you can, instead of FTP, I strongly recommend you to use the [Azure App Service Deploy task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/deploy/azure-rm-web-app-deployment?view=azure-devops) task.

It has a checkbox flag which take app offline before deploying files.
[image]

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but unfortunately, neither of those suggestions would help me as I'm not deploying to Azure. I should have made it clearer in the question, but I'm deploying to a regular IIS box. Do you know any way of achieving the same thing in this case? Thanks again.

Comment: This post talks about ASP.Net Core but this works the same way for .Net Framework
https://www.marcusfelling.com/blog/2018/deploying-iis-hosted-asp-net-core-apps-using-app_offline-htm/
Put app_offline.html at your site root, IIS detects it, then IIS tries to gracefully shutdown apppool, upload yours files, remove app_offline.htm, ISS restart apppool

Comment: thanks for the link, that's a new one on me! Will have to try it when I next deploy.