# How do I configure a build on VSTS to FTP deploy

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

I want to use VSTS to build and deploy my app (to FTP) when Update the master branch of my project. I have the script below. It works in that it triggers and builds but then fails to deploy because it can't find the files and I don't know what values to enter. I get the error below.

When VSTS builds, where does it put the build files?

[image]

I've watched youtube but all the examples are old and don't reflect how VSTS works right now so I'm totally stuck. There are no articles here that reflect how VSTS works right now and the Microsoft pages are no help either.

I'm running out of articles to review and am now pretty much guessing, so any help would be very much appreciated.

```
# ASP.NET Core
# Build and test ASP.NET Core projects targeting .NET Core.
# Add steps that run tests, create a NuGet package, deploy, and more:
# https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/devops/pipelines/languages/dotnet-core

trigger:
- master

pool:
  vmImage: 'ubuntu-latest'

variables:
  buildConfiguration: 'Release'

steps:
- script: dotnet build --configuration $(buildConfiguration)
  displayName: 'dotnet build $(buildConfiguration)'

- task: FtpUpload@2
  inputs:
    credentialsOption: 'inputs'
    serverUrl: 'ftp://xxxxxxx.xxxxxxxx.xxxxx/'
    username: 'xxxxxxxxx'
    password: 'xxxxxxxxxx'
    rootDirectory: '/'
    filePatterns: '**'
    remoteDirectory: '/'
    clean: false
    cleanContents: true
    preservePaths: false
    trustSSL: false
```

I changed to this

```
rootDirectory: $(Agent.BuildDirectory)
```

and tried this

```
rootDirectory: $(Build.StagingDirectory)
```

And now the build succeeds but now I get this error/warning. Nothing is deployed.

[image]

Comment: you don't copy anything to '$(build.stagingdirectory)' so there won't be anything to upload

Comment: you'll have to add a copy-task or point to the build-output of your project instead

Comment: Just want to check whether below method could help you catch the success pipeline. If it is no help for your issue, feel free to leave comment below:-)

Comment: Manually, I can do a publish to a local folder, then zip/unzip to my host. What I was hoping is that when VSTS does a build it puts the files in some folder (similar) to the publish location and then I could add a task or something to do the copy bit. I just dont know how or where the published files go

Comment: Okay, seems got to know what's your trouble. In this issue, does the confusing you are facing is do not know where is the files/folders go after the `dotnet build` steps finished? Then, this lead you got mislead on `rootDirectory`?

Comment: @MerlinLiang-MSFT Yes that's correct when the build is finished **I do not know** the correct parameter for that folder. I do not know where the build files are put. Do you know what value I should be using?

Comment: Of course yes. In fact, you could find these in the detailed log of the **build**(set system.debug=true firstly): https://imgur.com/a/tExAIHH And then, if you want to familiar with which variable represent this path, you could check this [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/build/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#build-variables). I ever faced the same puzzle with you when I firstly take this VSTS. That doc is a wonderful guide when you analyze the log(at least so do I, hope same for you)

Answer (score 0):

When you set `system.debug=true`, then open the log for detailed compile process, you could see:

[image]

It is looking for directory '`/`' which you specified in the task. But, unfortunately, the content obtained with `/` is not any part of your repos. Then the server tell you sorry, can not find such file or directory in your repos.

This parameter is getting files or folders from your VSTS repos, so here you need use some words to let server know what you want to take from Repos.

---

**(1)** Since this task is in your build pipeline, you could use [`$(Build.SourcesDirectory)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/build/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#build-variables) to represent for your whole repos.

**(2)** Also, if you just want to copy part of repos, such as folder or file, just input them with relative path. For example:

- Upload the file `upload.json` which under the folder `jobs`, just
  input `rootDirectory: jobs/upload.json`.
- Upload one folder or file which in the root path of Repos, just input
  `rootDirectory: {folder name}`, or `rootDirectory: {folder name}`. Like: `rootDirectory: jobs`, or `rootDirectory: web.config`

Comment: I don't want the who repo. I just want the location of the file created when the application builds so that I can transfer them to the web server

Comment: @djack109, Just want to confirm is any assistance I can give to you? If this answer is useful for you, you can accept it which will benefit for other community.